# Unable to generate DaggerAppComponent in Dagger2 in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

I googled and tried all things to generate DaggerAppComponent in my simple kotlin project. Im totally new to Dagger2 and would be lovely if you can give me a sample or tips to this problem! I would love to hear from you!

Cant generate the DaggerAppComponent...

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
   DaggerAppComponent.builder().build().inject(this)
```

I realized the Dagger2 doesnt generate when I add inject method in AppComponent.

Comment: Any error message you get?

Comment: Cant even import.. just red when I type DaggerAppComponent. Cant even get errors

Comment: Did you run "Build project" to generate code from Dagger? Can you edit question and add code for component and modules?

Comment: I dont have my computer with me now... I wonder, arn't there any samples that work properly?

Comment: Class `DaggerAppComponent` is created by Dagger for you, from your Component. If your component name's `MyComponent`, generated class would be `DaggerMyComponent`. But since those are build in compile time, to get those classes in IDE, you have to hit "Build project".

Comment: Take a look over this link, it should help you to get an idea and start working. https://github.com/jurajkusnier/android-app-template